# Is there an event that fires before the vscode editor is closed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension should display a message box when the editor is closed. 
The user should confirm before the editor is closed.

The only events I could find in the VSCode API are `onDidCloseTerminal` for the terminal 
 and `onDidCloseTextDocument` for text documents.

Comment: I don't think such an event exists.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions can export a `deactivate` method along with their `activate` method that will be invoked when VS Code is shutdown

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  ...
}

// Called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {
     ...
}
```

See [the extension activation docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up) for more details

Comment: Does this ever get triggered? I thought an extension, once loaded, stays active all the time, until vscode is closed, or at least as long as an editor is open for which this extension is registered. In both cases it won't help the OP.

Comment: I took them to mean the entire "VS Code editor" but it's possible they are talking about individual document editors

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [issue 99694](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99694) (for the upcoming Oct. 2020 VSCode 1.51 "Search editor: support to reopen closed editor" feature):

> Via [1eac96d](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/1eac96d162f7ab7792e271e6dad12cf1ef31a29b) there is now support to reopen closed editors if they implement an editor input factory. Previously we would only allow files to reopen.

You can see in those sources the `isDisposed()` method, which was generalized to all generic editors in [VSCode 1.49](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49) (August 2020) with [commit 17c1929](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/17c1929af632ff078cd4d4a9f081757b13fe264b).

So check if the event `onDispose` ([tested here for instance](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f74e473238aca7b79c08be761d99a0232838ca4c/src/vs/workbench/test/browser/parts/editor/editorInput.test.ts#L64-L73)) would work in your case.

---

Note that VSCode 1.51 (Nov. 2020) will adds a  new setting `window.confirmBeforeClose`, introduced to show a confirmation dialog before closing or leaving the workbench.

> Possible values are:
>
> - **`keyboardOnly`** (default): the confirmation will only be shown when you use a keybinding to close (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)
> - **`always`**: the confirmation will always be shown, even if you close from a mouse gesture
> - **`never`**: the confirmation will never be shown
>
> [image: Close Confirmation]