Is there an event fired on 'IDE is closing' action in API?
I need to create a modal dialog prompt in extension asking whether the user wants to save data when they close Visual Studio Code. Is there an event in the API fitting this purpose?

"asking whether the user wants to save data" what data specifically? Is it data in your extension?

@phuzi, yes, I'm referring to the extension's data.

I don't think there is. Would it be possible to save the data as soon as it changes?

Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358974/is-there-an-event-that-fires-before-the-vscode-editor-is-closed ?

I have found 'workbench.action.closeWindow' command, maybe it can help.

or the dispose method

@phuzi, no, we need to ask the user if the changes should be saved

There is no event for that, neither any plans to implement it.
